# C# Simple File Server (For uploading)

Tags: c#, file, file-upload

I want to write on C# very tiny simple file server for uploading and storing files of size 1-4 MBs. Please give me advice how to make it in shorten time without coding everything by myself. Maybe you could recommend some library or engine for it;)

Thank you very much!!!

Comment: Regular share folder works fine for your requirements - no C# code at all... Or you need something else like FTP server?

Comment: You could implement an FTP server.  The FTP protocol is very simple, and there might be existing C# classes built into the framework for writing one.  I know there is an existing FTP client, `FtpWebRequest` - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.aspx.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/saurabhnandu/FileSharingServerinCSharpn.NET12032005003904AM/FileSharingServerinCSharpn.NET.aspx